# python matplotlib basemap show polygons in a map

Tags: python, matplotlib, geospatial, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to render a polygon using python matplot Basemap lib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

def render_polygon(lat, long):
  map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-10,llcrnrlat=35,urcrnrlon=35,urcrnrlat=60.,
                                  resolution=None, projection='tmerc', lat_0 =
                                  8.30, lon_0 = 3.46)
  map.plot(lat, long, marker=None,color='m')
  plt.show()

lat = [56.1304, 55.1304, 54.1304, 53.1304, 52.1304]
long = [106.3468, 107.3468, 105.3468, 104.3468, 103.3468]
render_polygon(lat, long)
```

When I run the program passing the latitude longitude I see an empty rectangle.
Can someone point out what am I doing incorrect?

Comment: Please show the data (lat, long), including the lines of code that make use of `render_polygon()`.

Comment: @swatchai updated the data that uses render_polygon

Answer (score 1):

You need to transform coordinates in the process.
Try changing

```
map.plot(lat, long, marker=None, color='m')
```

to

```
map.plot(*map(long, lat), marker=None, color='m')
```

The code `*map(long, lat)` does the required coordinate transformation, and spreads the result to xs, ys in that place.

**Edit 1**

The original code have been edited to get appropriate data extent, proper projection parameters.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

def render_polygon(lat, long):
  map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=103, llcrnrlat=50, urcrnrlon=107.5, urcrnrlat=60.,
                resolution='c', projection='merc', 
                lat_0 = 50, lon_0 = 105)
  map.plot(*map(long, lat), marker=None, color='m')
  #map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.7)
  plt.show()

lat = [56.1304, 55.1304, 54.1304, 53.1304, 52.1304]
long = [106.3468, 107.3468, 105.3468, 104.3468, 103.3468]
render_polygon(lat, long)
```

The output plot:

[image]